# how to enable sql log in openjpa?

Tags: jpa, logging, openjpa

I have proram written using java,jps.Now i can see logs on cosole as folllows:

INSERT INTO XYZ (a,b,c) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement]

I also want to see the values passed to insert query in log.How can i see it?AM using openjpa as jpa provider.

Answer (score 2):

Set [openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties=PrintParameters=True](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_logging_channels).